# How to best structure web flows consisting of multiple paths and goals

Tags: usability, workflow, onboarding

We have a process where a user uploads a file and then is shown a results page with information we've gleaned from their file as well as the option to:

1. explore search results related to their input file
2. drill down into our recommendations of things they could improve with their file
3. explore some specific data we've analysed/extracted from their input file.

In this case, the file they are uploading is their CV.

We currently have one results page and two separate pages for 2 and 3. We don't currently guide the user through the process.

Are there any good examples of web flows with multiple paths and goals we can look at to take inspiration from? Many of the obvious flows only have one goal: user sign up, e-commerce checkout etc.

**Edit**:

The flow is currently as follows:

```
Landing page 
-> Upload File
-> Login/Signup
-> View Results
   -> Explore job search results
   -> Explore CV improvement recommendations
   -> Explore career guidance
```

Steps 2. and 3. (above) are currently separate pages linked via prominent buttons on the initial post-upload page, which contains summary information about their CV as well as job results.

From a small sample of initial user testing we understand that users are feeling a bit lost and unsure of what they should be doing when they get to the results page.

We plan to solve this partly by improving the landing page they visit before uploading their file but we also feel that the results page(s) themselves need improving.

We're not sure which option(s) to try to make the results more understandable and useful.

We could present the different paths as a step-by-step flow and guide the users through it. We could present a tooltip based tour of how to use the results. We could hold back some of the information and drip feed it via email. We could split the whole thing up into different results for different use cases with their own landing pages.

There are probably additional ways we could present or guide the user through the information/flow which I haven't thought of, which is why I asked for examples.

Comment: Please don't come to a site of UX experts and ask us to give examples of other sites. *Ask us directly what the best approach here is*. This is a Q&A site, not a link aggregator and we are full of people who can likely solve your problem *directly* rather than providing a bunch of links to places that may be useful or may just be junk. Can you explain your situation in a bit more detail (what you've done and what it is you're trying to achieve) and we can give you some potential solutions. Questions just asking for lists of examples will likely be closed off.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've tried to expand upon the question to make it more appropriate. Perhaps it's not a good question for a Q&A site and if so, please accept my apologies and feel free to close it.

Comment: Without knowing a lot more about your potential users, this question is probably still too broad to answer.  Each of your proposed solutions could fulfill different user needs. For example, a "tooltip based tour" might work well if you expect your users to interact with your product often enough that they're willing to learn how to use it. A "drip feed via email" would be more suitable for bored or distracted users who have no specific task in mind. Giving "different use cases [..] their own landing pages" could be good if most of your users need to use only one of your services.

Comment: Thanks @3nafish, I've come to the conclusion from this that we're still a bit unsure of our user needs which is something we'll need to address. I like your point about tooltips as well, certainly this won't be something users will use often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know the details of the service context and targeting (or anything else, for that matter), but if this is a job searching service I think first user need (matching job offers) is much bigger (more important for the user) compared to two other. So it should differ visually and take more important place/be more accessible than two other CTA's.

For example,

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll give you the answer points because it was a poorly asked question. I think we're at a stage where we can't ask a useful question yet and need to do some more exploration of our idea and potential customers.

Comment: Thanks, Adam, good luck with the exploration and happy holidays to you & your team.